# Getting the topic id in alfresco share discussion

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am implementing email notification for alfresco share discussion. I am able to get the notification whenever new topic is created. But the topic id is wrong. I am getting link for the entire discussion topic list rather than that particular topic.

Here is my javascript snippet

```
var mail = actions.create("mail");
mail.parameters.subject = "New Post in Discussion:   " + document.parent.childAssocs["cm:contains"][0].properties.title;
//mail.parameters.template = companyhome.childByNamePath(template);
mail.parameters.text="A new post is available in the  " + document.parent.childAssocs["cm:contains"][0].properties.title + "site. " +  "site. It was added by" + person.properties.firstName +" "+ person.properties.lastName+ " \r\n You can view it through this link : http://sameer/share/page/site/"+document.parent.childAssocs["cm:contains"][0].properties.title +"/discussions-topicview?topicId="+document.parent.children[0].name+"listViewLinkBack=true";
```

The topic id `topicId="+document.parent.children[0].name` is not working. How to get the topic id.

Comment: As a generic rule, using the Node Browser to find what node you want, what properties you want, and how the node is related to others is normally the best way to go to discover the answer yourself

Comment: wondering if document.parent.children[0].name == document.name or do you want to get the name of a sibling node?

Comment: When you say it is not working what does it give you?

Comment: instead of this post id ,1403180485266_5328 I am getting fe7fc88b-ade3-4264-a61b-9ef3719c8367

Comment: Are you certain the given code sample is what you're using? You appear to be returning document.parent.children[0].id, not the name.

Comment: Both returning  fe7fc88b-ade3-4264-a61b-9ef3719c8367